# Manually edit records on Slave DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

## Scenario:

Primary DNS BIND server is down. I need to edit a DNS record on the slave server from IP address from x.x.x.1 to x.x.x.2

I go to my zone file, increase the serial number, edit the record, save the file, and reload the name*d service successfully.

However, when I do nslookup on the edited record I only get the old entry of x.x.x.1 and not the IP I changed it to. I go back to the zone file and I see the correct IP Address of x.x.x.2.

I'm manually checking the DNS record against the slave server:

```
C:\Users>nslookup myDNSrecord.enterprise.com 9.9.9.9
Server: SlaveDNS.enterprise.com
Address: 9.9.9.9
Name: myDNSrecord.enterprise.com
Address: x.x.x.1 Enterprise.com
```

Why is it that my slave DNS server does not appear to be updating the records I change manually?

Comment: When you use `nslookup`, are you explicitly pointing it at the slave DNS server? Can you share the commands you're using and what the responses are?

Comment: Hello Wesley and thanks for your reply.
Note: 
9.9.9.9 is my Slave server's IP
x.x.x.1 is what was configured on my Master DNS 

Now Master DNS is Down and need to change the IP Address of "myDNSrecord" on the Slave DNS to point to x.x.x.2 

This is the NSLOOKUP from desktop.

C:\Users>nslookup myDNSrecord.enterprise.com  9.9.9.9
Server:  SlaveDNS.enterprise.com
Address:  9.9.9.9

Name:    myDNSrecord.enterprise.com
Address:  x.x.x.1

Enterprise.com Zone file shows this:

myDNSrecord       IN A    x.x.x.2

thanks

Comment: "Why is it that my slave DNS server does not appear to be updating the records I change manually?" it may depend on bind version, configuration and how you do the change and if you restarted your nameserver or not. Bind uses binary journal files for zones in some cases, in which case your manual changes will not be taken into account... except if you reconfigure the secondary as a primary...